# Get number of copied files with XCOPY

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file to backup a directory. The .bat works fine, but in my LOG.txt I write some info, and one of them is supposed to be the amount of files copied. I state here that counting the number of files in the directory after the `XCOPY` has finished won't work, unless it counts every file in every subfolder in the directory.

What I have so far:

```
@echo off


SET dct-light_src= dir

For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set dct_light_startting_date=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set dct_light_startting_time=%%a%%b)

SET starttime=%dct_light_startting_date%

IF EXIST C:\Users\user\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup_%starttime%\ ( 
    MD C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup%starttime%\dctlight_backup
    SET dct-light_dtn=C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup%starttime%\dctlight_backup
    echo A folder for this backup already exists. Beggining overwrite...
) ELSE ( 
    MD C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup_%starttime%\dctlight_backup
    SET dct-light_dtn=C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup_%starttime%\dctlight_backup\
)

XCOPY %dct-light_src% %dct-light_dtn% /w /e /y

For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set dct_light_finished_date=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set dct_light_finished_time=%%a%%b)

SET startdate=%dct_light_finished_date%
SET starttime=%dct_light_startting_date%_%dct_light_startting_time%
SET finishedtime=%dct_light_finished_date%_%dct_light_finished_time%

CD C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dctlight_backup__%starttime%\

echo.LOG of %starttime%'s Backup>LOG_%startdate%.txt
echo.Start time: %starttime%>>LOG_%startdate%.txt
echo.Finished time: %finishedtime%>>LOG_%startdate%.txt

pause>nul
```

I have tried `FOR` to count the files in the destination directory, but did not work, and I haven't found any leads on how to store the number of files that `XCOPY` shows after it finishes copying.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counting all of the files in the current directory and all subdirectories.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /A "N=0"

FOR /F %%f IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D "*"') DO (
    SET /A "N=!N!+1"
)

ECHO N is %N%
```

PowerShell makes many things easier.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object { $_.Count }
```

or

```
(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Measure-Object).Count
```

If you must run it from a .bat script, the following can be used.

```
FOR /F %n IN ('powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Measure-Object).Count"') DO (SET /A "N=%n")
```

Another way would be to capture the output of the XCOPY command into a file, then count the applicable lines from there.

Comment: Thanks, mate. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but how could I do the same thing, but just to count the folders inside a DIR, excluding files and subdirectories, only folders?

Comment: `DIR /A:-D` does everthing except directories. `DIR /A:D` does only directories. See the output of the `DIR /?` command.